# Best practice to rename a Java file with Eclipse/Subversive over Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

We are using Eclipse/Subversive over Windows with TortoiseSVN installed for looking at things at directory level. Now here when we rename (refactor) any Java class with Eclipse it does not automatically renamed in SVN and we have to do kind of delete and add-new which is not a good practice.

What I believe we can do is "rename" a file in Repo-browser of TortoiseSVN and than refactor the class name in Eclipse.

Share if there is a better way to make sure that when we change it from Eclipse (I mean refactor/rename a class name), it affects SVN in a proper way.

Comment: It's not "subversive" it's "subversion"

Comment: are you using "subclipse", the eclipse svn plugin?

Comment: @PeterWooster subversive is an alternative eclipse plugin for SVN

Comment: I am using (subversive) http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/ which is a eclipse plugin for subversion.

Comment: Is subversive actually working for your project? When you right click a file in the project, what do you see under the Team menu?

Comment: yeah, that's subversive and it works for rest of the stuff but rename is not being handled properly as in java when we rename (refactor) class name it is being done by Eclipse w/o notifying plugin about that rename event.

Comment: Are you using the most up to date version of Subversive, and SVN? Does anything odd show up in the SVN console?

Answer (score 1):

Install SVN Eclipse plugin [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). It will handle renames properly in your SVN workspace.

With it installed, you have full SVN support in Eclipse. Including proper SVN move support when you rename a file in Eclipse file explorer.

Comment: subclipse is a useful plugin, however there are a lot of things that work better from Tortoise.  I wish tortoise was available on the Mac, I miss it.

Comment: @PeterWooster Did you checkout http://superuser.com/questions/58225/tortoisesvn-for-mac yet? (I do not have a Mac myself, so I have no experience with this)

Comment: Thanks!  Last time I looked I didn't find that.  I'm currently using Cornerstone, but have been moving to Git as it is well supported on the Mac.

Comment: Subversive also supports renames

Comment: @artbristol I did not say anything about it supporting renames, if suggested to use Subclipse as I *know* it supports renaming. Instead of down-voting me, provide your own answer how to rename files properly using subversive, that would help the OP much better!

Comment: @Veger subversive should be renaming files properly out-of-the-box. The OP seems to have some configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

With Subversive plugin installed (I'm using v1.8....), open the SVN Repository Exploring perspective.
In the "SVN Repositories" view, contextual menu on each file propose Refactor>Rename... dialog box, also accessible on F2 key and you're done.